# Dynamic expression (or plotting) in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

I just want to see dynamic evaluation inside manipulate. I have long equations inside manipulate. And want to see dynamically my listplot. I make simple example. But i see only dynamic controls, but not results of equations.

```
Manipulate[{Dynamic@x, Dynamic@y}, 
 Grid[{{Control[{{x, 0, "x="}, 0, 1, .01}]}, {Button[
     Text["Run"], {y = 0; f[]}, ImageSize -> 100, 
     Method -> "Queued"]}, {Dynamic[
     ProgressIndicator[y, {0, 1}, ImageSize -> 100]]}, {Dynamic[
     Text@Row[{Style[y*100, 11], Style["%", 11]}]]}}, 
  Spacings -> {0, .3}], {{y, 0}, None}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {x},(*does nothing,just for testing*)
 SynchronousUpdating -> False, SynchronousInitialization -> False, 
 Initialization :> (f[] := 
    Module[{i}, 
     Do[Pause[.15]; y = i; 
      x = i, {i, 0, 1, .01}] (*Pause[] to slow it down*)])]
```

How can i see dynamicaly updating {x, y} or listplot inside of manipulate body?
Thx.

Comment: The shortest way is to use stupid `Dynamic@First@List@y` because there is a bug which makes `Dynamic[y]` less sensitive than it should be.

Comment: `Dynamic@{x, y}` or `{Dynamic[x, TrackedSymbols :> {x}], Dynamic[y, TrackedSymbols :> {y}]}` instead of `{Dynamic@x, Dynamic@y}` does update as expected.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!